# class file created in netbeans is not running in cmd

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I have created some programs in netbeans.
I have compiled the programs in netbeans.
The class files where created.
But when I run these class files in command prompt,
It shows "could not find or load main class".
I took class file and run in another computer still same error.

What could I need to do if I need u run this class file alone to another computer???

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong from the information you've given. Could you post a small [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example and the specific steps you've taken to try to compile and run it?

Comment: What you are executing from command line? How those commands look like. From which directory relative to directory with classes you are executing those commands?

Comment: I copied the class file to d drive and located my drive in cmd and I used java filename.class command

Answer (score 0):

Did you try compile from cmd also? And if you can give your cmd command, we will help you better.

Comment: I compiled it only in netbeans.I copied the class file to d drive and located my drive in cmd and I used java filename.class command

Comment: *.class usually use in compile command: "javac filename.class"